# Validating a choice field with ModelSerializer with Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model **BaseUser** which inherits from **AbstractUser** and has two additional fields: complex_list and active_complex. complex_list is a ManyToManyField connected to the **BaseComplex** model through an enrollment table.

I want the default value for active_complex to be null which can be taken care of at the model initiation. I also need the user to be able to choose the active_complex only from the values within the complex_list. For that, I tried to use a customized ModelSerializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import BaseUser



class ActiveComplexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    this_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_this_user')

    choice =[]
    qs = BaseUser.objects.get(username = this_user)
    for cmplx in qs.complex_list:
        choice.append((cmplx.id, cmplx.name))

    active_complex = serializers.ChoiceField(choices = choice)


    class Meta:
        model = BaseUser
        fields = ('active_complex')

    def get_this_user(self, request):

        return request.user
```

I know I'm doing something wrong because I get a query not found ERROR. I would appreciate it if you could correct this or suggest a better approach to achieving the same goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the current code is that when you're calling

```
qs = BaseUser.objects.get(username = this_user)
```

`this_user` is not bound to any specific value. This code runs only once when the Class is first initialized, *not* on every new instance of the class.

You instead want to get the user when the serializer class is initialized and then populate the choices.

Here's a rough change, I have not tested this, but it should more or less work.

```
class ActiveComplexSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    this_user = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_this_user')
    active_complex = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=[])

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choice =[]
        qs = BaseUser.objects.get(username = self.fields['this_user'])
        for cmplx in qs.complex_list:
            choice.append((cmplx.id, cmplx.name))
        self.fields['active_complex'].choices = choice

    class Meta:
        model = BaseUser
        fields = ('active_complex')

    def get_this_user(self, request):
        return request.user
```

Also on a side note check out `get_user_model()` from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model - it is preferred to use that function instead of direclty importing user model.

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful, especially the get_user_model() which practically solved my problem. Just that the 'choices' parameter of ChoiceField should be an iterable and it would not take None as a value. So, for future reference this works just replace the None with an empty list '[]'

Comment: Awesome, I updated the code example. I'm glad I could be of help ^_^. Also props to you for writing a well-formed question with all the context available :)